# Use GCM / Firebase without clientside SDK

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to use GCM without any GCM related logic on the client side? The idea is that mobile app shouldn't store / renew tokens etc. Mobile app should just initialise session with the middleware backend which will return back the internal device id and that's it (backend server will register device in GCM / APNs).

The goal is to reduce client side logic and simplify integration, so the flow probably should look like: APP <-> BACKEND <-> GCM

Comment: I think I know what you are asking but what to make sure. You are saying you want the client to NOT register with GCM to get a registration token, but rather the backend server?

Comment: yes @opt05 I want my backend server register every device in GCM. So mobile device shouldn't even know its gcm-token.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can, the documentation states "this app must register with GCM and get a unique identifier called a registration token". There is a whole song and dance the client has to do with GCM that a backend isn't allowed to do. Plus, if the GCM server doesn't know which device is which registration id, it wouldn't know what client to send a notification to.

To GCM documentation states only one process of registering a client:

1. The client app obtains a registration token using the Instance ID API. The call to this API must have the authorized entity set to your app server's sender ID, and the scope set to the appropriate value for GCM (depending on your platform). Refer to the API reference for full detail on this API.
2. The client app passes the registration token to the app server.
3. The app server saves the registration token and acknowledges to the client app that the process completed successfully.

Comment: But then, how services like Parse / OneSignal / Ionic are work? In their flow you shouldn't register any GCM / APNs token on the app side. Integration is as simple as few lines of code on client side and their backend handle the rest.

Comment: When you add their SDKs/library files to your project, they do that work for you, so it looks like less code. You still have to supply the GCM Sender ID on the client side so it can register with your GCM project.